# PHP Rock,Paper,Scissors Game Error

Tags: php

**rps.php**

This program's function is to allow a player to choose an option between rock,paper and scissors and then send the choice to a second page which should display a picture of their option, versus the randomized computer option.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="keywords" content="Rock,Paper,Scissors">
<meta name="description" content="An automated game that plays rock,paper, 
scissors with you.">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<title>Rock Paper Scissors Game</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
Rock Paper Scissors Game
</h1>
<form action="rps2.php" method="get">
<p>
<input type="radio" name="player" value="1">Rock
<input type="radio" name="player" value="2">Paper
<input type="radio" name="player" value="3">Scissors
</p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Play"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**rps2.php**

This program's function is to choose which picture displays depending on 
which option the player chooses and to randomly choose a picture to for the computer that the player is up against. The problem is that none the information is transferring from the first page to the next, is validated and the form action is directing to the right page.

```
  <?php
    $player = 
    substr(filter_input(INPUT_GET,'player',FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),0,1);
    $computer = rand(1,3); #Rock 1, Paper 2, Scissors 3
    #Display Player/Visitor Hand
    if ($player == 1) 
    echo "<p><img src=\"rock1.png\" alt=\"image of rock\">";
    elseif ($player == 2)
    echo "<p><img src=\"paper1.png\" alt=\"image of paper\">";
    elseif ($player == 3)
    echo "<p><img src=\"scissors1.png\" alt=\"image of scissors\">";
    #Display Computer Hand
    if ($computer == 1) 
    echo "<p><img src=\"scissors2.png\" alt=\"image of scissors\">";
    elseif ($computer == 2)
    echo "<p><img src=\"rock2.png\" alt=\"image of rock\">";
    elseif ($computer == 3)
    echo "<p><img src\"paper2.png\" alt\"image paper\">";
    ?>
```

Comment: Just for clarification, if I seem like I have no idea what I'm doing. I deeply apologize, I'm a student and I'm just trying to learn and figure this out one at a time. Please bear with me, any help if very greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you've done doesn't look too bad.  What is the error you're getting?

Comment: You are missing equals (=) characters in the second last line, so if computer gets paper, no image will appear

Comment: Your code is working fine. What error you are getting?

Comment: Thank you. I put the equals in,it still didn't change anything,but still thank you.

Comment: When I upload my files to my server and play the game myself. The pictures do not show up at all.

Comment: I made sure all my spaces were right and that I had all of my semicolons. Then uploaded my pictures and all of my files and again and everything works properly. Thank you all very much.

Comment: So there is no longer an issue? If so you can delete the question, or post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

rps.php
[Correct code for program 1]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="keywords" content="Rock,Paper,Scissors">
<meta name="description" content="An automated game that plays rock,paper, scissors with you.">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<title>Rock Paper Scissors Game</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
Rock Paper Scissors Game
</h1>

<form action="rps2.php" method="get">
<p>
<input type="radio" name="player" value="1">Rock
<input type="radio" name="player" value="2">Paper
<input type="radio" name="player" value="3">Scissors
</p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Play"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

rps2.php 
[Correct code for program 2]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="keywords" content="Rock,Paper,Scissors">
<meta name="description" content="The data from an automated game that plays rock,paper, scissors with you.">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<title>Rock Paper Scissors Game</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Rock Paper Scissors Game</h1>
<?php
$player = substr(filter_input(INPUT_GET,'player',FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),0,1);
$computer = rand(1,3); #Rock 1, Paper 2, Scissors 3
#Display Player/Visitor Hand
if ($player == 1) 
echo "<p><img src=\"rock1.png\" alt=\"image of rock\">";
elseif ($player == 2)
echo "<p><img src=\"paper1.png\" alt=\"image of paper\">";
elseif ($player == 3)
echo "<p><img src=\"scissors1.png\" alt=\"image of scissors\">";
#Display Computer Hand
if ($computer == 1) 
echo "<p><img src=\"scissors2.png\" alt=\"image of scissors\">";
elseif ($computer == 2)
echo "<p><img src=\"rock2.png\" alt=\"image of rock\">";
elseif ($computer == 3) 
echo "<p><img src=\"paper2.png\" alt=\"image paper\">"; 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Furthermore, this might be a bit clearer:
`$rpsArray = [
    1 => "rock",
    2 => "paper",
    3 => "scissors"
];

echo "<p><img src=\"{$rpsArray[$player]}1.png\" alt=\"image of {$rpsArray[$player]}\">";
echo "<p><img src=\"{$rpsArray[$computer]}1.png\" alt=\"image of {$rpsArray[$computer]}\">";`

Comment: Thank you for the extra help.

Comment: Try to understand what's going on there, you'll be able to produce it yourself in the future.

Comment: Thanks again.  Very nice of you to help